# How do I stop animation for the initial load when using knockout.js with foreach binding and 'afterAdd'

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have specified a afterAdd binding so that when I'm adding a item to a observableArray I get a pretty slideDown effect. Works great, looks cool.

Problem is on the initial load. I'm loading from a data source and setting the observableArray to the returned json data. Imagine 20 items on the screen all sliding down at the same time. Not so cool. How can I stop that from happening?

Slide function:

```
vm.addItem = function (elem) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 1) { $(elem).hide().slideDown(); }
};
```

Looks nice when adding a single item:

```
vm.postComment = function () {
    $.post('Place/PostComment', { placeId: vm.placeId(), comment: vm.comment() }, function (comment) {
        vm.comments.push(comment);
        vm.comment('');
    });
};
```

Not so nice when setting the initial value. Sliding down for each added:

```
vm.loadPlace = function () {
    $.getJSON('Place/GetComments', { placeId: vm.placeId() }, function (data) {
        vm.comments(data.Comments);
    });
};
```

**Update 11/16/2012 Morning**

From Vyacheslav Voronchuk's suggestion my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="placeComments" data-bind="foreach: { data: comments, afterAdd: addItem, afterRender: renderedComments, beforeRemove: removeItem }">
```

Javascript looks like this:

```
vm.renderedComments = function () {
    loading = false;
};

vm.addItem = function (elem) {
    if (!loading) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
            $(elem).hide().slideDown();
        }
    }
};

vm.loadPlace = function () {
    $.getJSON('Place/GetPlace', { placeId: vm.placeId() }, function (data) {
        loading = true;
        vm.comments(data.Comments);
    });
};
```

Still seeing the animation. Using the debugger I can see that it enters the addItem function twice.

On a side note I'm guessing this is why the documentation uses fadeIn instead of slideDown. Maybe I should switch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vm.loadPlace = function () {
    $.getJSON('Place/GetComments', { placeId: vm.placeId() }, function (data) {
         vm.loading = true;
         vm.comments(data.Comments);
    });
};

vm.addItem = function (elem) {
   if (elem.nodeType === 1) { 
      if(!vm.loading) {
         $(elem).hide().slideDown(); 
      }
   }
};
```

In your view, add `afterRender` where you will set `vm.loading = false`.

Comment: It looks like it loops through addItems twice, once when loading is true but then comes back after it's false. Not sure if I have something wrong with my code or why it would be doing this, but will update my answer with my latest code.

Comment: For now I'm just going to switch to fadeIn. I thought your answer would work, but not sure how to get around how the addItem is called "both when foreach first initializes, and when new entries are added to the associated array later." (from the documentation)

Comment: Can you please show how you initialize your `comments` observable array?

Comment: I may suggest you to use `.extend({throttle: 1000})` option for your observableArray. If you can create a jsfiddle, it will be much easier to resolve.

Comment: Ok will try to do that. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you.